# Jquery textcomplete not shows data from server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

i want to create an application which can tag or mention users, and i am using this plugin https://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/

but i can't able to show data from php json encode data

fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/gtjL9ruy/

```
$('.textarea4').textcomplete([
      { 
        match: /(^|\s)@(\w*)$/,
        search: function (term, callback) {
          callback(cache[term], true);
          $.getJSON('http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d6b7ebe62f80da1c206f0653fe87f859', { q: term })
            .done(function (resp) { callback(resp); })
            .fail(function ()     { callback([]);   });
        },
        replace: function (value) {
          return '$1@' + value + ' ';
        },
        cache: true
      }
    ], { maxCount: 20, debounce: 500 });
```

Comment: Your source is no JSON its an HTML page

Comment: if i write a php file there 'server.php' and print 
echo json_encode($data); 
its not working

Comment: Give more info in the question, what does consoling `resp` gives, does network tab show any error,What exactly is the issue you are facing?

Comment: here you can see my json data and when i am typing on textarea it shows some error http://recordit.co/xibnATL0UB

Comment: Your server is not giving valid json it seems